# Magento 2 override resource model collection not working

Tags: magento2, collection, di

I want to override Magento Reports module and it's not working. here's my code :

**di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection" type="SZK\Shamsi\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection" />
```

**SZK\Shamsi\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection**

```
namespace SZK\Shamsi\Model\ResourceModel\Report;

use Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection as OrgCollection;
use Morilog\Jalali\jDate;

class Collection extends OrgCollection
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $localeDate, $collectionFactory);
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $dateStart
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getDayInterval(\DateTime $dateStart)
    {
        $interval = [
            'period' => jDate::forge($dateStart)->format('Y-m-d'),
            'start' => $this->_localeDate->convertConfigTimeToUtc($dateStart->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')),
            'end' => $this->_localeDate->convertConfigTimeToUtc($dateStart->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59')),
        ];
        return $interval;
    }
}
```

everything seems ok but it's not working.

Comment: where is the location of your di.xml

Comment: Check your custom and third party modules , same class is override or not in any modules.

Comment: di file is in etc,  and no, it's not override by thrd party modules.